# How to grep 2 or 3 lines, one containing the text I want, and the others just below it

Tags: linux, grep

I have a script that prints out information regarding running jobs.
I'm interested to capture name and status (Wait/Run)
They are located on different lines (status is below name)

`name = any_name`

`status = Wait`

I tried:

```
myScript -status | grep name
```

How to display also status together with name?

Comment: why not modify `myScript` to optionally show basic output (as is), but make the default output the format you prefer. Less code, more reusability ;-) . Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data file:

```
test
name = any_name
status = Wait
some data
```

Search for `name` and grep line after (grep and awk)

```
grep -A 1 "name" file
awk '/name/ {p=2} p--' file
name = any_name
status = Wait
```

Search for `status` and grep line before (grep and awk)

```
grep -B 1 "status" file
awk '/status/ {print s"\n"$0} {s=$0}' file
name = any_name
status = Wait
```

Comment: Works well, thanks! 
Also in case I want to find specific name:
`myScript -status | grep -A name | grep -A specific_name`

Answer (score 0):

`grep -C 1` shoud do the job.

From the manpage of grep:

> Print  NUM  lines  of  output  context.

Comment: `grep -A 1` seems to be better.